# android adb devices doesnt work anymore after a while

Tags: android, macos, cordova, ionic-framework, adb

I'm developing ionic android apps on macOS.

"adb devices" usually works as intended, when I have an android device plugin in. I have USB Debug enabled and the device is also authorized.

However after a certain amount of time, the same pattern appears, after which I can't find the device anymore.

1. The system promt for authorization pops up out of nowhere. Regardless where I confirm or reject it, adb device doesn't show the device anymore.
2. Unplugging and plugging it in again doesn't work. Disabling USB Debugging Mode and revoking authorization doesn't work either.
3. I've also tried adb kill-server with no avail.

So far the only reliable way is restart my computer.

Does anybody have a clue whats happening?

Comment: Have u tried ur phone on another pc ? try to install android studio and run your app.